# How to listen to events using Web3 v1.0?

Tags: web3js, events

I have a problem when listening for events from my contract.

Code js :

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var abi = '...';
var contractAddress = '0x62e7Dd1Af52d5A08D401b1e156cC4CB1d2f89d57';
var eventName = 'Transfer';
//var web3;
var etat;
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
/*
var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0x78e97bcc5b5dd9ed228fed7a4887c0d7287344a9');

// watch for an event with {some: 'args'}
var myEvent = myContractInstance.Transfer({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
myEvent.watch(function(error, result){
    console.log(result)
});

// would get all past logs again.
var myResults = myEvent.get(function(error, logs){ console.log(logs) });



// would stop and uninstall the filter
myEvent.stopWatching();
*/



var TokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi),contractAddress);
TokenContract.events.allEvents({ fromBlock: 'latest' }, console.log)
console.log('1********************************************************************************')
console.log(TokenContract);
console.log('2********************************************************************************')
var event = TokenContract.events.Transfer();
console.log(event);
console.log('3********************************************************************************')

TokenContract.once('Transfer', {
}, function(error, event){ console.log(event); });

event.watch(function(error, result){
    if (!error) {
        alert("wait for a while, check for block Synchronization or block creation");
        console.log(result);
        console.log('pas d erreur');
    }else {
        console.log(error);
        console.log('erreur')
    }
});
```

I have tested a lot of possibilities but the function `.watch` doesn't run :

```
TypeError: event.watch is not a function
```

**How do you listen to events using Web3 1.0?**

Comment: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events

Comment: check `var event = TokenContract.events.Transfer();`. Does it work? `event` var has an object?

Comment: same issue.... anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22771)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

event.watch is not a function in web3.0 v1.0

Use the snippet below instead, but remember that:

- `myContract` should be a variable you assigned which is an instance of your contract
- `MyEvent` should be replaced with the actual name of your event.

> ```
> myContract.events.MyEvent({
>     filter: {myIndexedParam: [20,23], myOtherIndexedParam: '0x123456789...'}, // Using an array means OR: e.g. 20 or 23
>     fromBlock: 0
> }, function(error, event){ console.log(event); })
> .on('data', function(event){
>     console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
> })
> .on('changed', function(event){
>     // remove event from local database
> })
> .on('error', console.error);
> ```

Also see the docs [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id36).

Comment: Should this emit all past events? Seems to only emit the last even for me

Comment: In this particular case the params state `fromBlock: 0` so it _should_ emit everything past block 0... However, based on your node provider it might not work. Try downloading a full node on your computer and executing it on that full node.

Comment: @Tarrence In fact please use [getPastEvents](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents)

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'MyEvent' of undefined..anyone else?

Comment: Having same issue.  events are undefined.

Comment: Did you guys properly define myContract?

Comment: not working ,neither error is coming nor i am getting event in callback.

Comment: Perhaps something with your web3 and blockchain connection.

Comment: @thefett instead of `MyEvent` put the actual name of your event.

Comment: @Eddy thanks, I'll update my answer to reflect that note.

Comment: Note: Code example from https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events

Comment: should be `contractObj.contract.events.YourEventName...`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could only listen to past events, but new events didn't come through. If you're in the same situation, add an indexed parameter to the event in the contract, and filter by it on the front-end. The event will start showing up.