# Solidity Event Handling

Tags: solidity, web3js, events

I have been trying to listen to the event of my smart contract; however, I receive the error.

```
MyContract.events.myEvent(

function(error, event){ 
    if(!error){
        $("#instructor").html(event.args.name + ' (' + event.args.age + ' years old)');
    }else{
        console.log(error); 
    }
    
})
```

I receive the following error

```
 Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions:
```

Web3.js version is **web3@1.3.0**

I am well aware of the [following](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35997/how-to-listen-to-events-using-web3-v1-0) solution; however, it doesn't work on my case anyway.

My smart contract

```
contract Coursetro {
    
   string fName;
   uint age;
   
   event Instructor(
    string name,
    uint age 
    );
   
   function setInstructor(string _fName, uint _age) public {
       fName = _fName;
       age = _age;
       Instructor(_fName, _age);
   }
   
   function getInstructor() public constant returns (string, uint) {
       return (fName, age);
   }
    
}
```

Comment: which provider are you using to listen to events. you need to have WebSocket enabled provider to listen to events in Ethereum

Comment: I just gave an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As @myanzik-shresth mentioned, you will need to use `WebsocketProvider` in order to subscribe to an event if you are using version `web3.js@1.x`

Use

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:8545'));
```

Not

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
```